# How to draw a dynamic curve that can be controlled by the slider

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

Can a dynamic sine curve be controlled by the user in runtime? For example if the user controls the sine curve using a slider, then the curve should change from the time the value was changed (and not the entire visible curve).

Comment: See answer below sorry...

Answer (score 0):

It all depends on your visual representation.

Using:

`clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)`

will clear the whole canvas and you would have to maintain information about your sine wave that was drawn previously.

It's possible to use it like this:

`clearRect(theta, 0, period, canvas.height)`

I.E. Only redraw the section of the canvas you wish to give the user control of and then redraw the modified sine wave.

Here is a fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/UkR4G/1/

As you can see, I only clear a portion of the curve, leaving you free to redraw a different frequency wave in this section.

How you do this is up to you.

Comment: Can you please show me an example for the usage of clearRect(theta, 0, period, canvas.height). It would be very helpful.